# How do you make vertical addition equation with MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

I want to make something like this with MathJax:

1 2 4
+ 5 3
------
1 7 7

How would I go about doing so? I searched on the TeX website, but people only gave answers with stuff like ${\$\$}$\begin{tabular}{cccc}$$, which only works for LaTeX, and not MathJax. Is there a way to render the above equation in MathJax, and how?

Comment: Array works with MathJax. It has a lot of common with tabular. See, for example http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6734/how-can-i-put-a-table-here, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-insert-a-table-when-asking-a-question and other questions, that are linked there.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I don't want a table in my addition equation... Is it impossible to create an addition equation vertically without having to create a table? At the very least, make the table edges invisible if at all possible.

Comment: JChau: So [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14424286#14424286) is not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One could use the `array` environment:
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&124\\
+\!\!\!\!\!\!&53\\
\hline
&177
\end{array}
$$
$\LaTeX$ source:

```
\begin{array}{r}
&124\\
+\!\!\!\!\!\!&53\\
\hline
&177
\end{array}
```

Comment: @DanielR: anytime there is MathJax, you can right-click on the rendered MathJax and choose "Show Math As > TeX Commands".

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Using only one column and adding some (positive) space after the plus is better than using negative space to fiddle with the two column spacing, in my opinion.  I think the other version will fail in native MathML mode in firefox, for example, as it doesn't handle negative space very well.

\begin{array}{r}
124\\
+\quad 53\\
\hline
177
\end{array}

Answer (score 4):

If you don't like "array", there is also "align"
$$\begin{align}
124& \\
\underline{+\quad 53}& \\
177&
\end{align}$$

> `$$\begin{align}
> 124& \\
> \underline{+\quad 53}& \\
> 177&
> \end{align}$$`