# Vertically aligned addition equation with MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

I'm working on math project and I need to create simple vertical addition or subtraction equations. I read this page [Page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13168/how-do-you-make-vertical-addition-equation-with-mathjax?newreg=559400561248497e9ff48dd6cef69e5e). I'm using `MathJax` for this project.

If I'm using integers everything looks ok

$$\begin{align}
124& \\
\underline{+\quad 53}& \\
177&
\end{align}$$

but when I add decimals everything moves into wrong places:
$$\begin{align}
12,4& \\
\underline{+\quad 53}& \\
177&
\end{align}$$

as you can see 5 is not under 2 (answer is incorrect this is just an example)

another example

$$\begin{align}
124& \\
\underline{+\quad 53.258}& \\
177&
\end{align}$$

decimals numbers should be on the right.

```
$$\begin{align}
124& \\
\underline{+\quad 53.258}& \\
177&
\end{align}$$
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One lazy fix is to use phantoms:

Expanding the decimal expansions lines things up:

```
$$\begin{align}
124\phantom{.000}& \\
\underline{+\quad 53.258}& \\
177\phantom{.000}&
\end{align}$$
```

$$\begin{align}
124\phantom{.000}& \\
\underline{+\quad 53.258}& \\
177\phantom{.000}&
\end{align}$$

A more correct way is to put the & (alignment) to the left of the decimal point on each line, and use \hline:

```
$$\begin{align}
124 & \\
 +\quad 53 &.258 \\
\hline 
177 &
\end{align}$$
```

giving

$$\begin{align}
124& \\
+\quad 53 &.258 \\
\hline
177&
\end{align}$$

Comment: Nice.  I've been wanting to know how to show long division, e.g., as well. Something like $$27\, \vert \overline{\;54\quad}$$ with the result, 2, above the overlined 4, of 54.  Of course it gets even trickier with a, b where $a \not\mid b$.

Comment: @amWhy I would also be interested by long division (and square root as well, but it's close). However, it's amazing, I had absolutely no idea that even for this there were so many differences (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) vs [this](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_pos%C3%A9e) - no need to read french, see the examples - as well as other languages).

Comment: Yes!  Thanks for the links, @Jean-ClaudeArbaut !

Comment: As for the division, I would try something like :
`$$
\begin{align}
&\phantom{\sqrt{1}}0\\
256&\sqrt{1729}
\end{align}$$`
I.e.,:
$$
\begin{align}
&\phantom{\sqrt{1}}0\\
256&\sqrt{1729}
\end{align}.$$

The spacing is hard to get right; using array {rl} is another possibility, but you may have to add `\!`s to the right of the & to narrow the gap.